# How to crop an image prior to exporting it on VBA 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have a subroutine working just fine to export an image taken from a range in excel, but I´m facing a problem... Even when I managed to make the chart object transparent and without a border... the exported image has a lot of unused area that I wish to crop before exporting it.

```
Sub BtnSaveFile_Click()

Dim RgExp As Range
Dim ImageToExport As Excel.ChartObject

Const sSlash$ = "/"
Const sPicType$ = ".png"
Dim sChartName$
Dim sPath$
Dim sBook$

Set RgExp = Range("G4:N28")

RgExp.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

Set ImageToExport = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=RgExp.Left - 80, Top:=RgExp.Top - 80, Width:=RgExp.Width - 80, Height:=RgExp.Height - 80)

With ImageToExport.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill
.Visible = msoFalse
End With

With ImageToExport.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Line
.Visible = msoCFalse
End With

ImageToExport.Chart.Paste

Start:

sChartName = Application.InputBox("Enter A Name Of Your Choice" & vbCr & _
"There Is No Default Name Available" & vbCr & _
"The File Will Be Saved At C:\SECTIONIZER\SAVED SECTION\", "PROVIDE A NAME FOR THE VIEW", "")

If sChartName = Empty Then
MsgBox "Please Enter A File Name", , "Invalid Entry"
GoTo Start
End If

If sChartName = "False" Then
ImageToExport.Delete
Exit Sub
End If

sBook = "C:\SECTIONIZER\SAVED SECTION"
sPath = sBook & sSlash & sChartName & sPicType
ImageToExport.Chart.Export Filename:=sPath, FilterName:="PNG"
ImageToExport.Delete

ExitProc:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set ImageToExport = Nothing
Set RgExp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I had the idea to crop it by seeking the first black pixel at each side of the image (left,top,right,bottom), so I can then set the coordinates to crop out the empty pixels, but I haven´t found a code to do so.

**EDIT:** added images from OP's supplied links

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: You don't have enough rep to attach pictures but you could upload some to imgur or some other site and add the link to the question. I think seeing what you're dealing with will help.

Comment: Thank you Paul! Here is the link of the actual image export: http://i.imgur.com/piQSJ45.png And here is the link of the wanted outcome: http://i.imgur.com/mmneK7e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. First of all, I grouped all the shapes at the excel range, with the group selected, established W and H of the selection to later attribute it to the Width and Height of the Chart to be added, then on the added chart Pasted the Copied Selection... Here is the final outcome:

```
Sub BtnSaveFile_Click()

Dim ImageToExport As Excel.ChartObject
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim RangeToTest As Range
Dim CC As Range
Dim DD As Range

Const sSlash$ = "/"
Const sPicType$ = ".png"
Dim sChartName$
Dim sPath$
Dim sBook$

'The images at the range are selected and grouped 
Set RangeToTest = Range("G4:N28")

For Each CC In RangeToTest

    Set ShpList = Sheets("SECTIONIZER").Shapes

    For Each Shp In ShpList
        If CC.Address = Shp.TopLeftCell.Address Then
            Shp.Select Replace:=False
        End If
    Next Shp

Next CC

Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select

'W and H are established with the above selected group Width and Height
W = Selection.Width
H = Selection.Height

'Selected group is copied as picture
Selection.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

'Chart Object is Added with the W and H values
Set ImageToExport = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, W , H)

   With ImageToExport.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    With ImageToExport.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoCFalse
    End With

    'Group Selected is then Pasted into the above added Chart
    ImageToExport.Chart.Paste

Start:
         '   Pop Up Window For User To Enter File Name
        sChartName = Application.InputBox("Enter A Name Of Your Choice" & vbCr & _
        "There Is No Default Name Available" & vbCr & _
        "The File Will Be Saved At C:\SECTIONIZER\SAVED SECTION\", "PROVIDE A NAME FOR THE VIEW", "")

         '   User presses "OK" without entering a name
        If sChartName = Empty Then
            MsgBox "Please Enter A File Name", , "Invalid Entry"
            GoTo Start
        End If

         '   If Cancel Button Is Pressed
        If sChartName = "False" Then
            ImageToExport.Delete
            Exit Sub
        End If

         '   If A Name Was Given, View Is Exported As A *.PNG Image
         '   At C:\SECTIONIZER\SAVED SECTION
       sBook = "C:\SECTIONIZER\SAVED SECTION"
       sPath = sBook & sSlash & sChartName & sPicType
       ImageToExport.Chart.Export Filename:=sPath, FilterName:="PNG"
       ImageToExport.Delete

ExitProc:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set ImageToExport = Nothing
Set RgExp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Here are some examples of the exported images: http://i.imgur.com/MJLGLf2.png, http://i.imgur.com/Om97kMj.png (couldn´t add them on my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to start the macro recorder and then crop the picture to the area of your liking, and then you can use the coordinates recorded in your subroutine. The following is a sample of what you will get

```
Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = 196
Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = 196
Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX = 0
Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetY = -8
```

Comment: Thank you, that partially solves the query! The main problem is that the image to be exported isn´t always the same size... so the cropping has to adapt to the different image sizes. Do you have any ideas on how to code a searching of the first black pixel on every side of the image (so the values for cropping are established once the first black pixel is found).

Comment: Hi Adry, if that is the case you will need to use the object library of an image processing software like Photoshop. Here is something to get you started http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-VBScript-Ref.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I´ll dig into it! If you have any other ideas that would be great :)